# How to access notebook from JupyterLab extension activate method?

Tags: javascript, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Some time ago I wrote an extension for JupyterNotebook. Now I want to adapt it for JupyterLab.

In order to access the currently opend notebook I used:

```
var notebook = Jupyter.notebook;
var firstCell = notebook.get_cells()[0];
```

=> What is the corresponding code for Jupyterlab?

```
module.exports = [{
    id: 'jupyterlab_workspace_module',
    autoStart: true,
    activate: function(app) {
       //app.notebook is not defined
       var notebook = getNotebook(app); // <= how to implement this?
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var notebookPanel = __getFirstVisibleNotebookPanel(app);
var notebook = notebookPanel.content;
var cell = notebook.activeCell;

function __getFirstVisibleNotebookPanel(app){
    var mainWidgets = app.shell.widgets('main');
    var widget = mainWidgets.next();
    while(widget){
        var type = widget.constructor.name;
        if(type == 'NotebookPanel'){  //other wigets might be of type DocumentWidget
            if (widget.isVisible){
                return widget;
            }
        }
        widget = mainWidgets.next();
    }
    return null;
}
```